# Graphql insert a child while indicating his parent

Tags: graphql

I'm very new into graphql but I'm able to insert a new "notification" that belongs to a "Tienda" which means store, however I'm not able to indicate to which store it belongs to.

This is the schema

```
type Tienda @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  cliente: [Cliente] @manyToMany(relationName: "clienteDeTienda")
  news: [Notificacion] @hasMany

}

type Cliente @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  stores: [Tienda] @manyToMany(relationName: "clienteDeTienda")  
}

type Notificacion @model {
  id: ID!
  store: Tienda @belongsTo
  content: String!
}
```

This is how I insert a new notification:

```
const response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNotificacion, {input:data}))
```

This is what data has inside:

```
Object {
  "content": "Nueva notificacion",
}
```

And this is the response I get from console.log(response):

```
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "createNotificacion": Object {
      "content": "Nueva notificacion",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-13T18:04:55.000Z",
      "id": "9f50d333-fc9e-478f-be6a-c54275797a27",
      "store": null,
      "tiendaNewsId": null,
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-13T18:04:55.000Z",
    },
  },
}
```

As you can see "content" was added to the notification but "store" is null but I haven't been successful in inserting the store ID in there.

This is how the mutations is defined:

```
export const createNotificacion = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateNotificacion(
    $input: CreateNotificacionInput!
    $condition: ModelNotificacionConditionInput
  ) {
    createNotificacion(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      store {
        id
        name
        cliente {
          nextToken
        }
        news {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      content
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      tiendaNewsId
    }
  }
`;
```

I've tried with the following 3 methods which give no error but still doesn't link to it's parent:

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNotificacion, {input:data, store:{id:'55988776-11af-42b8-b93b-9de9af35f7dc'}}))
```

And

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNotificacion, {input:data, store:'55988776-11af-42b8-b93b-9de9af35f7dc'}))
```

And:

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNotificacion, {input:data},{store:'55988776-11af-42b8-b93b-9de9af35f7dc'}))
```

Please somebody point me the right path or documentation about how to do this. I need to know how to perform the graphqlOperation correctly.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show what's in your `data` variable as well as how the mutation is defined. Bottom line is that you're going to need to pass the `id` of the Tienda to the mutation along with the notification data.

Comment: Thank you, I've just added that. I understand that I will need the id but I tried with several formats and I wasn't able to do it. I has to be done where I insert the new notification but don't know how.

Comment: Your `data` variable needs the tienda id. `Object { "content": "Nueva notificacion" }` doesn't have enough data for the mutation to infer a tienda relationship.

Comment: That's what I tried to do but I wasn't able. Tried by inserting "store":"someStoreId", also with graphqlOperation(createNotificacion, {input: {...data, ['store']:'someValidStoreID'}}) but I get this error "The variables input contains a field name 'store' that is not defined for input object type 'CreateNotificacionInput' "

Comment: Look at the *typeDefs* on the server (or introspect the schema). How are the parameters of `createNotificacion` defined. Not how you are using them but how *should* they be used?

Comment: Where can I see how the should be used? I looked different documentations but they don't show how to define the parent of a child at the moment of creating them. Edited the post to show another things that I've tried, which give no error but it doesn't link to his parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249571/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-mrpie).

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I had to do is this:

```
const response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNotification, {input:{...data, storeNotificationsId:'someValidStoreId'}}));
```